# How to install library in the google plat form - ai platform - notebook instance

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, anaconda, jupyter-lab, cudf

I currently a data science undergraduate student and try to use google could platform - AI platform - notebook instance to do data science project. The following image shows what I am talking about.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

I have no problem running the instance and use it to manipulate the data.
However, since I want to use cudf library to accelerate the data processing speed, I need to install that library.
By searching from internet, I have tried:
First, I opened the terminal:

---

[image]

---

then I tried the following command and got the errors:

---

[image]

---

the command is from this [website](https://pypi.org/project/cudf/)
2.Then I tried use the anaconda way to install it, use the method from the same [website](https://pypi.org/project/cudf/)I type in the following command in the terminal and got the 'UnsatisfiableError'.

---

[image]

---

From the above, you can see I have tried both 10.0 version and 9.42 version, but both of them does not work.
3. Then I also tried use the method from this [website](https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf). I typed the following command `conda install -c nvidia -c rapidsai -c numba -c conda-forge -c defaults cudf=0.8 python=3.6 cudatoolkit=9.2` on the terminal, the result is very long so I just show last part:

---

[image]

---

As you can see, this time the installation is successful. But then when I open a new note book and import the 'cudf' library following error appears:

---

[image]

---

it said there is no such library, but I just installed the library.

I am really appreciate anyone who could solve this problem for me as I have been struggling on this for 7 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to install dependencies in an AI platform notebook you should indeed use pip (have a look at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/dependencies)). 
However, it seems that [RAPIDS is not working anymore with PIP installation packages](https://medium.com/rapids-ai/rapids-0-7-release-drops-pip-packages-47fc966e9472) and therefore the proper approach to install it is by creating a Docker image or installing it using conda. In their [GitHub Library](https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf) you can see more information on how to do it.

[In this link](https://hub.docker.com/r/rapidsai/rapidsai/) you will find the Rapids Docker repository where you can pull a Docker image with the required dependencies to run cuDF and [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/custom-container) you will find the steps to create an AI Platform Notebook instance using a custom container.

As AI platform notebooks is in Beta stage, it is possible that the functionality of installing conda packages is not yet available.

As a workaround I suggest you to install cuDF packages in a notebook running ‘PyTorch’ environment instead of the ‘Numpy/SciPy/scikit-learn’ that you are using as its default pip version is older (19.1.1). To do so you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/create-new) and see how to set the ‘PyTorch’ environment.

---